# Path of recent creation time of a single file using C#

Tags: c#, fileinfo

How to get the path of the recent or latest file  based on creation time (say 'test.xml) located in many sub directories within a main directory.

Comment: What do you mean by recent creation time? There is only one time at which a file has been created...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .OrderBy(File.GetLastWriteTime)
         .Last()
```

If you're not using .Net 4.0, change that to

```
Directory.GetFiles(path, "*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
         .OrderBy(p => File.GetLastWriteTime(p))
         .Last()
```

This is somewhat slower, but will work in .Net 3.5.

Comment: That's no correct solution. It gives you the max time, but not the File Path as requested.

Comment: @TToni: You're right; fixed.  Thank you.  It would be faster with a loop or `Aggregate` instead of a sort, but I'm too lazy for that.